# How to only match a single instance of a character?

Tags: regex

Not quite sure how to go about this, but basically what I want to do is match a character, say `a` for example. In this case all of the following would not contain matches (i.e. I don't want to match them):

- `aa`
- `aaa`
- `fooaaxyz`

Whereas the following would:

- `a` (obviously)
- `fooaxyz` (this would only match the letter a part)

My knowledge of RegEx is not great, so I am not even sure if this is possible. Basically what I want to do is match any single `a` that has any other non `a` character around it (except for the start and end of the string).

Comment: Which lang ar you running?

Comment: abaco should match, right?

Comment: abaco should match both As or shouldn't match at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically what I want to do is match any single a that has any other non a character around it (except for the start and end of the string).

```
^[^\sa]*\Ka(?=[^\sa]*$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/2)

`\K` discards the previously matched characters and lookahead assertes whether a match is possibel or not. So the above matches only the letter `a` which satifies the conditions.

**OR**

```
a{2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|a
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/3)

Comment: or `^[^a]*\Ka(?=[^a]*$)`

Comment: Im not sure from his example if disjoint 'a's in the same word should match 2 'a' s or neither

Comment: or `a{2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|a` ,, https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/3 . Donno what exactly op wants, so I provided both.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I want to be able to match it on a single line (I think my use of bullet points in my question may have been confusing). For example `babbbbab` should match twice.

Comment: The second RegEx you provided works great thanks. What environments would this be supported with, I haven't seen `SKIP` mentioned before? I will be running this with `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`.

Comment: java won't support this freature, so you could use this https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/4 . Get the `a`'s you want from group index 1. or use negative lookaround based regex https://regex101.com/r/wE7nB6/5

Answer (score 3):

You may use a combination of a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
(?<!a)a(?!a)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT7npx/1/) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!a)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a `a` char
- `a`  - an `a` char
- `(?!a)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a `a` char.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

- a negated character class: `[^a]` *(all except "a")*
- anchors (`^` and `$`) to ensure that the limits of the string are reached (in other words, that the pattern matches the whole string and not only a substring):

Result:

```
^[^a]*a[^a]*$
```

Once you know there is only one "a", you can use the way you want to extract/replace/remove it depending of the language you use.